# Android using Flickr API

Tags: android, flickr

I am trying to connect to Flickr on Android for a learning project of Big Nerd Ranch of Android, but there is always an Exception:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
```

the code I is like:

```
public class FlickrFetchr {
private static final String TAG="FlickerFetchr";
private static final String API_KEY="075a834f9703a704c763d335f";

 byte[] getUrlBytes(String urlSpec) throws IOException {
     URL url=new URL(urlSpec);
     HttpURLConnection connection=(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

     try {
         ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();

         if(connection.getResponseCode()!=HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)
             return null;

         int bytesHead=0;
         byte[] buffer=new byte[1024];
         while((bytesHead=in.read(buffer))>0){
             out.write(buffer,0,bytesHead);
         }

         out.close();
         return out.toByteArray();

     }catch(Exception e){
         Log.e(TAG,"Read Exception ",e);
         return null;
     }finally{
         connection.disconnect();
     }
 }

public String getUrl(String urlSpec) throws IOException {
    return new String(getUrlBytes(urlSpec));
}

public void fetchItems(){
    try{
        String url= Uri.parse("https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/").buildUpon().appendQueryParameter("method","flickr.photos.getRecent")
                .appendQueryParameter("api_key",API_KEY)
                .appendQueryParameter("format","json")
                .appendQueryParameter("nojsoncallback","1")
                .appendQueryParameter("extras","url_s")
                .build().toString();
        String jsonString=getUrl(url);
        Log.i(TAG,"Received XML:"+ jsonString);
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG,"Failed to fetch",e);
    }
}
```

}

Am I doing something wrong here? Any comment is really appreciated!

Comment: You should also add to url parameters: oauth_version, oauth_nonce, oauth_signature_method, oauth_consumer_key, oauth_token, oauth_timestamp. Read more here: https://www.flickr.com/services/api/auth.oauth.html

Comment: This code turns out to be fine. There are problems with emulator but it worked fine on real devices such as Samsung Sony etc. So there is nothing wrong with the code